# Name of the natural bijection between $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $[c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: terminology

Given $[a,b],[c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}$, we can take the natural bijection between those intervals

$$\phi: [a,b] \to [c,d] \\ x \mapsto (x-a) \frac{d-c}{b-a} + c$$

Does this bijection have any name?

Comment: It's can be dubbed the unique nondecreasing affine bijection between these intervals, but I doubt anyone has ever cared to giv a specific name to it. (Introducingthe name would take longer than thinking of the map)

Comment: How about "the linear map"?